# I want to display selected records of page 1 on page 2.Both pages share the same controller.How would I do that?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class AccountSelectClassController1{

    //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects wrapAccount
    public List<wrapAccount> wrapAccountList {get; set;}
    public List<Account> selectedAccounts{get;set;}

    public AccountSelectClassController1(){
            String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            if(wrapAccountList == null) {
            wrapAccountList = new List<wrapAccount>();
            for(Account a: [select Id, Name,BillingState, Website, Phone from Account limit 10]) {
                // As each Account is processed we create a new wrapAccount object and add it to the wrapAccountList
                wrapAccountList.add(new wrapAccount(a));
            }
        }
    }

    public PageReference processSelected() {
    PageReference congratsPage = Page.WrapperAccountEXChild;
    congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
       selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();
         for(wrapAccount wrapAccountObj : wrapAccountList) {
            if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true) {
                selectedAccounts.add(wrapAccountObj.acc);
                 congratsPage.getParameters().put('id', wrapAccountObj.acc.id);


            }
        }
    return congratsPage;
    }

    // This is our wrapper/container class. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Account and a Boolean value
    public class wrapAccount {
        public Account acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public wrapAccount(Account a) {
            acc = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Page 1 :

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSelectClassController1" sidebar="false">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
            var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
                if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                    inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Show Selected Accounts" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table2"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageblockSection title="All Accounts" collapsible="false" columns="2">

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapAccountList}" var="accWrap" id="table" title="All Accounts">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.acc.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.acc.BillingState}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.acc.Phone}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Page 2 :

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSelectClassController1">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="c" id="table2" title="Selected Accounts">
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" headerValue="Account Name"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.BillingState}" headerValue="Billing State"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Phone}" headerValue="Phone"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Why don't you use one page with 2 sections instead? You can render one or another either server side by using the `reRender` attribute, or you could do that with VisualForce remoting and some javascript (show/hide).

Comment: Akash, it would probably help if you explain your code and how it's not doing what you expect or where you don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Bachovski :   I've tried the approch you suggested but my requirement is to display it on seperate page.

Comment: Samuel : I'm accessing account records on page 1 and you can select any number of records using checkboxes (Wrapper class concept).I use one command button and set the page Reference to page 2 by onclick button.Now I want to display selected records of page 1 on page 2.I'm stuck with passing the id's of selected records to page 2 and thats why it's not showing any records but just displaying empty page block.

Answer (score 3):

Where multiple pages share the same controller the state established in one page is transferred to to the next page automatically. This allows things like multi-page [wizards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm) to be created.

But you have this [setRedirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) in your code:

```
congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
```

which:

> This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and flushes the
>   view state, which uses POST. If set to false, the redirect is a
>   server-side forward that preserves the view state if and only if the
>   target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of
>   extensions used by the source page.

So remove that line.

**PS**

This is all you should need in your method:

```
public PageReference processSelected() {
    selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();
    for (wrapAccount w : wrapAccountList) {
        if (w.selected) {
            selectedAccounts.add(w.acc);
        }
    }
    return Page.WrapperAccountEXChild;
}
```

with the second page able to access the view state created by the first page.

Comment: I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with that? I got stuck and couldn't solve the issue yet..Please post the suggested code or link.
Thank you.!

Comment: @Akash See the PS. If that doesn't work I'm not sure what is wrong.